# Flexbox row won't work, forces column layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to learn flexbox and do some project using it but whenever I set my container to `display: flex` my rows are turned into columns and `flex-direction` property like doesn't respond, it won't make them into rows.

What am I doing wrong? I'm going insane because of this, current code looks like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 45vw;
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="row" style="background: blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `flex-direction` property you set on the `container,` not the `row` . Should these be stacked vertical or horizontal?

Comment: On top of each other. And it doesnt matter, even if I set direction on parent element the rows stay as columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the items to stack vertical and create *rows*, you set the direction to `column`

*Note, the property `flex-direction` should be set on the flex container, not its items*

```css
.container {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 45vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  flex-basis: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="row" style="background: blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huh, it's completely counterintuitive for me, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @BigPaws I can be, though `flex-direction` property set the _direction_ the items should flow

Comment: I thought display flex was default behavior of all items. But after looking at your answer, I realized I should also apply display flex to the container I am applying flex direction to. I did and it worked. Thanks a lot.